# how to get a widget from QListWidgetItem

Tags: qt4

I made a `QListWidget`. In `QLisitWidgetItems`, i added a `QVBoxLayout`. That `QVBoxLayout` contain three `QLabels`. How to get the values inside `QLabel` while click `QListWidgetItem`

//creating list view items(three QLabels)

```
Lblnames::Lblnames(QString strid,QString strname,QString strmob,QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QLabel *lblid=new QLabel(strid);
        QLabel *lblname=new QLabel(strname);
        QLabel *lblnumber=new QLabel(strmob);

        lblid->setFont(QFont("Times", 1));
        lblname->setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont::Bold));

        lblid->hide();

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(lblid);
    layout->addWidget(lblname);
    layout->addWidget(lblnumber);
    setLayout(layout);
}
```

//creating list

```
listWidget=new QListWidget();
    for(int i=0;qry.next();i++)
    {
        qDebug()<<QString("%1").arg( qry.value(1).toString());
        Lblnames *lblnames = new Lblnames(QString("%1").arg( qry.value(0).toString()),QString("%1").arg( qry.value(1).toString()),QString("%1").arg( qry.value(2).toString()));
        item = new QListWidgetItem();
        item->setSizeHint(QSize(0,60));
        item->setFont(QFont("Arial", 1));
        listWidget->addItem(item);
        listWidget->setItemWidget(item,lblnames);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to add methods to LblNames to fetch the label text.Then
Declare the 3 Qlabels as member variables of LblNames class.

```
QString LblNames::getLabelId()
{
    return lblid->text();
}

 
QListItemWidget* item = listWidget->itemAt(index);
LblNames* widget = dynamic_cast<LblNames*>( listWidget->itemWidget(item) );
widget->getLabelId();/*Add these to LblNames class first*/
widget->getLabelText();
```

You should use google for such things . dynamic_cast is used to cast from a super class to one of its subclasses.

Comment: I agree the labels should be member variables, but if they are, you shouldn't need the dynamic cast anymore.  You can access them directly.

Comment: i have one more doubt.i have two classes (MyWidget,ViewContact).i create an object of ViewContact from MyWidget and call obj->show().while finish(this->close()) ViewContacts work ,i need to reload MyWidget class.please give me answer.THANKS..

Comment: The question is  very brief and i don't understand it, please be more specific and start a new question.

Comment: I think the casting should be `dynamic_cast<LblNames*>` according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast